# Order Cut off timer to include bank holidays

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

Please can someone help with this code? I currently have a countdown timer that counts to 3pm Monday to Friday.

So far it is mostly working, currently after 3pm on a Friday it adds 72 hours, Saturday it adds 48 hours and Sunday it adds 24  hours.

[here is a fiddle for this](https://jsfiddle.net/ej3981zs/)

I am trying to have it check whether the current day or the next working day is a bank holiday and then add on the relevant amount of hours to this. Ideally I'd be able to offer a list of dates that we won't ship.

```js
if (document.getElementById('countdown-timer')) {
  pad = function(n, len) { // leading 0's
    var s = n.toString();
    return (new Array((len - s.length + 1)).join('0')) + s;
  };

  var timerRunning = setInterval(

    function countDown() {
      var target = 15; // 14:00hrs is the cut-off point
      var now = new Date();

      //Put this in a variable for convenience
      var weekday = now.getDay();

      if (weekday == 5) { //It's Friday? Add 72hrs
        target += 72;
      }

      if (weekday == 6) { //It's Saturday? Add 48hrs
        target += 48;
      }

      if (weekday == 0) { //Sunday? Add 24hrs
        target += 24;
      }

      //If between Monday and Friday, 
      //check if we're past the target hours, 
      //and if we are, abort.
      var curhrs = now.getHours();

      var hrs = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
      if (hrs < 0) hrs = (23 - curhrs) + target;
      var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
      if (mins < 0) mins = 0;
      var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
      if (secs < 0) secs = 0;

      var str_hrs = pad(hrs, 2);
      var str_mins = pad(mins, 2);
      var str_secs = pad(secs, 2);

      document.getElementById('countdownhrs').innerHTML = str_hrs;
      document.getElementById('countdownmins').innerHTML = str_mins;
      document.getElementById('countdownsecs').innerHTML = str_secs;

    }, 1000
  );
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown-timer" class="">
  <div class="timer-container d-flex flex-row text-center text-nowrap">
    <div class="hrs">
      <span id="countdownhrs">00</span>
      <small class="d-block">HOURS</small>
    </div>
    <div class="separator">:</div>
    <div class="mins">
      <span id="countdownmins">00</span>
      <small class="d-block">MINS</small>
    </div>
    <div class="separator">:</div>
    <div class="secs">
      <span id="countdownsecs">00</span>
      <small class="d-block">SECS</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bank holidays / public holidays vary by country and region. Based on the terminology, I'm guessing you're looking for UK holidays? Even then, although it's possible to calculate the standard bank holidays, they can be changed by the government.

Comment: I wrote this a while ago. Perhaps useful: https://github.com/mplungjan/addHolidays

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are in the UK, the UK government publishes the bank holidays via a JSON API at:
https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json

It has separate lists for England and Wales, Scotland and Northern Ireland.

Here is some sample code to fetch the list and populate an array with just the dates for "england-and-wales":

```
let holidayList = [];

fetch('https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((divisions) => divisions['england-and-wales']['events'])
.then((holidays) => holidays.map((holiday) => holiday.date))
.then((days) => (holidayList = days));
```

The divisions available are: "england-and-wales", "northern-ireland", "scotland"

Documentation for the API is at:
https://github.com/alphagov/calendars

Comment: Since you're not using [an `async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), you'd need to move the `holidayDays` assignment inside the second `then` callback. Otherwise, the `holidayList` will still be empty, and there won't be anything to map.

Comment: Thanks @richard-deeming, I consolidated it all into a single fetch.